# Changing specific bit in large binary file

Tags: c, linux, file, binary

First thing, I'm working with large binary file (2-4 GB) on Linux 64bit and this file is also mapped from another process. So, the content in file is always changed all the time. I would like to change some bit at specific bit/location but don't have to read it.

**Just changing bit at specific address and don't care the rest of its content
additional edit : or set bit to be stuck all time. (that bit can't be changed)**

when I use hexdump to read it, it seems like this.

```
3ffbd280  00 00 78 32 fb 44 22 cc  44 11 22 aa b2 33 b2 c3
```

Any thought or idea is very welcome.

Comment: I'm not quite sure yet and still finding for a method.

Comment: Do you need to set the bit, reset the bit, or toggle the bit?  It is going to be hard, if not impossible, to adjust one bit without reading at least the byte containing that bit beforehand.  How is the bit identified?  Do you have a bit number in the entire file, or a byte number and the bit number within the byte?  Are you on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler maybe toggle, I just want it get changed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have bit/byte number. Please look at my edit for example. I'm using 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 64-bit Linux, the signature of [`fseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html) doesn't cause trouble; the offset parameter is a `long` which means it will be a 64-bit quantity and it can handle a 2-4 GiB file with ease.  If the question was for 32-bit Linux, or for 64-bit Windows, the story would be different.  You would have problems dealing with offsets between 2 GiB and 4 GiB.

Assume that the file stream is opened for reading and writing.  Assume that the bit position is specified via an absolute byte offset in the file plus a bit number (0…7).  Assume that the bit should change, so the operation toggles the bit from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1.  Assume that there is no need to keep a record of the current position in the file so it can be restored after flipping the bit.  Then the sequence of operations might be:

```
void flip_bit(FILE *fp, long offset, int bitno)
{
    int c;
    assert(fp != 0);
    assert(offset >= 0);
    assert(bitno >= 0 && bitno < 8);

    fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);
    if ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        c ^= 1 << bitno;
        fseek(fp, -1L, SEEK_CUR);  // Step backwards 1 byte
        putc(c, fp);
        fflush(fp);
    }
}
```

Each assumption you change triggers corresponding changes in the code.  It is necessary to `fflush(fp);` to maximize the chance of the change being made on disk so the other process sees it.  Also, the `fflush(fp)` means that it is safe to use the stream for input (or output) even without an intervening seek (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.5.3 **The `fopen` function**, ¶7):

> When a file is opened with update mode ('`+`' as the second or third character in the
>   above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the
>   associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
>   intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`,
>   `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an
>   intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end of file.

If you wish to ensure the bit is set, replace the assignment with:

```
        c |= 1 << bitno;
```

If you wish to ensure the bit is reset, replace the assignment with:

```
        c &= ~(1 << bitno);
```

Comment: Does offset mean "bit/byte address in whole file" ?

Comment: Yes.  The offset is the byte position in the file, starting at an offset of zero for the first byte, etc.  The bit number in the byte is separate.  You could encode things differently if desired.  But the question wasn't clear on how the bit to flip is identified, so I chose the easiest solution.  There are many variations you could use.  If the file is memory mapped in the process flipping the bit, then a whole alternative solution is needed.

Comment: It's been succeeded, thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE* fp = fopen( "bigfile.abc", "rb+" )  
//rb+ is important! see here: the wrong mode may clear/delete the file.
//http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/?kw=fopen

if( fp ) 
{
    unsigned char b = 0;
    fseek( fp, #_of_bytes_from_origin, SEEK_SET )
    fread( &b, 1, 1, fp );      //read 1 unit of 1 byte into 'b'

    b ^= (1<<bit_index);        //toggle the bit, as Jonathan said

    fseek( fp, -1, SEEK_CUR );  //go one byte backwards (you went forwards when reading)
    fwrite( &b, 1, 1, fp );     //write 1 unit of 1 byte back into the file
    fclose(fp);                 //close the file when done
}
```

This has just been my experience with C on 32-bit machines over the years, but I don't *think* any of the above would change on a 64-bit architecture, since you're being explicit about one *byte*.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/
and the core file functions: fopen(), fclose(), fseek(), ftell(), fread(), fwrite()

Changing a specific bit:

```
byte_to_change &= ~(1<<bit_index)
```

where bit_index is 0 through 7. This will set the bit to 0.

```
byte_to_change |= (1<<bit_index)
```

will set it to 1.

Comment: I would suggest that the terms should be 'reset the bit to 0' and 'set the bit to 1'.  You could add `byte_to_change ^= (1 << bit_index);` to 'toggle the bit', meaning flip it to 0 if it is 1 and flip it to 1 if it is 0.

Comment: Both the input, and more importantly, the *output* of said operation are missing. Changing a byte in-memory will do the OP little good until the byte is written back to the mapped file so the other process can see it.

Comment: Nicely done.  The only comment is that if you would run into problems if the file is bigger than 2 GiB and the system is a 32-bit system.  Fortunately, the OP is on a 64-bit Linux system, so there isn't an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. it's been succeeded.